# Javascript comparison of audio current time results in endless while loop

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am trying to have a event happen at a current time through an audio file. The following code currently works and successfully plays the audio file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .titletext {
                color: white;
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                font-size: 50px;
                width: 1000px;
                margin-left: 150px;
                margin-right: 200px;
            }
            .nametext {
                color: white;
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                font-size: 30px;
                width: 600px;
                margin-left: 500px;
                margin-right: 200px;
                margin-top: 600px;
            }
            .earthphoto {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                margin-left: 400px;
                margin-top: 150px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="update()">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.body.style.background="black";
            var changescene=function(){
                var allvariables=Object.keys( window );

                if(page===1){
                    console.log(allvariables);
                }

                page++;
                update();
            };
            var page=1;
            var playsound=function(){
                if(page===1){
                    document.getElementById("sound1").play();
                    document.getElementById("sound1").addEventListener("ended",function(){changescene();});
                }
            };
            var update=function(){
                if(page===1){
                    document.body.innerHTML="";
                    var text=document.createElement("p");
                    var textclass = document.createAttribute("class");
                    textclass.value="titletext";
                    text.setAttributeNode(textclass);
                    text.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Welcome to Mikey's Google Earth Presentation!"));
                    document.body.appendChild(text);
                    var text2=document.createElement("p");
                    text2class=document.createAttribute("class");
                    text2class.value="nametext";
                    text2.setAttributeNode(text2class);
                    text2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("By Mikey Richards"));
                    document.body.appendChild(text2);
                    googleearthimage=document.createElement("img");
                    googleearthimage.setAttribute("src","EARTH.png");
                    googleearthimage.setAttribute("class","earthphoto");
                    document.body.appendChild(googleearthimage);
                    var music=document.createElement("audio");
                    var musiclink=document.createElement("source");
                    musiclink.src="Slide1.mp3";
                    music.appendChild(musiclink);
                    var musicclass=document.createAttribute("id");
                    musicclass.value="sound1";
                    music.setAttributeNode(musicclass);
                    document.body.appendChild(music);
                    playsound();
                }else if(page===2){
                    document.body.innerHTML="";
                }
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, although this works for playing the audio file, when I add this code to run some code when it reaches a certain point, it crashes.

```
while(document.getElementById("sound1").currentTime<16){
}
//insert code here
```

I place this code in the playsound function directly after the play function for the audio, so the audio file should be playing. Why does the file crash.

Here is a link to see the result of the file:
http://www.presentation.bugs3.com/presentation.html

Comment: At least give a proper formatted code.

Comment: If you could format your code correctly, that would be a great help. Trying to read all left justified code with no meaningful indents is difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You effectively have a `while(true){}` loop in your code. `while` executes synchronously, which means that there is no break in the execution loop for anything else to happen, like the audio to advance. You only want to use `while` if the loop itself modifies the condition `while` is checking. Depending on exactly what you want to do, i'd use `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. If you want to stop it after 16 seconds, I'd do

```
setTimeout(
    function(){document.getElementById("sound1").pause()},
    16000)
```

alternatively

```
var curInterval = setInterval(
        function(){
             if(document.getElementById("sound1").currentTime<16)
             {
                  doSomething();
             }
             else
             {
                 clearInterval(curInterval);
                 doSomethingElse();
             }
        },
        200) //whatever interval makes sense to you.
```